# This tag is an [undefined-variable]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Should we burninate the [undefined-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-variable) tag?

- There are only 16 questions using it
- Questions that could make use of
  this tag are *generally* closed as a dupe of one of the FAQs or
  general help questions
- Perhaps a question that could use it without being
  duped as one of the FAQs doesn't really need it as the crux of the
  issue would be elsewhere

Comment: Your reasoning to remove the tag is not enough see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination. Without any future investigation to me it seems like a reasonable tag that can be useful for search engines. However there may be better tags, to replace it with?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Fair enough, not strongly debating this was just a thought as most "undefined" issues are duped to the FAQ questions.

Comment: It's very few questions, so probably there is a similar tag, but yeah in general if you like to get the community involved on a burniation you need a very good reason and comply with criteria in FAQ hence base your argument on that. I often argue that tag needs also to do some damage (confusion, encouraging off-topic questions, messing up search result etc) this since we have a big backlog of request. Many like to ask but unfortunately few participate.

Comment: I'll leave this here for searchability, in case someone else has the same "*bright idea*"

Comment: :), yeah that's a good idea, meta is not rep based but instead a place to throw out "bright idea's" to see if they can shed some light *or not*

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a tag isn't used very often isn't a reason to remove it, nor is the fact that many of the questions that use the tag are close-worthy. There are plenty of tags that routinely draw low-quality questions but don't really meet the criteria for burnination, such as [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn) (which draws many general computing questions, but also has at least some legitimate programming questions.

The fact that many people use the tag improperly doesn't mean that it *has* no legitimate use.